# Does every non-locally compact metric space admit a violation of Lebesgue's theorem?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, measure-theory

From the results of Preiss and Tišer, it is known that many natural families of measures on Hilbert spaces violate the Lebesgue Density Theorem. Question: Does every non-locally compact metric space admit a measure (on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra) for which the Lebesgue-Besicovitch Density Theorem fails?

Comment: What about countably many copies of $[0,1]$ glued at $0$? (assuming you are talking about locally finite measures, etc.)

Comment: hmm, so I guess not true...